# PyQt post installation question

Tags: python, pyqt4

I successfully installed PyQt in both mac and PC. To do so I had to install mingw (on PC), Xcode (on MAC) and Qt4.6 library. Now that I have PyQt working perfectly, I would like to uninstall mingw, Xcode and Qt Library from both mac and PC.

I know I can remove Xcode and mingw, but what care should I take before removing Qt library. I know PyQt is still using it but it is not using whole 1.5Gig of files installed by Qt installer. So which files should I copy before removing Qt and where should I copy it to.

Comment: this question is almost 2 weeks old, but if you (or others) are still looking for an answer I'm posting one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `demos` and `examples` directories inside your qt installation directory... they take up over 1GB of space and are not required. I would leave the rest there, unless you are really worried about space.

If you *do* try to clean up the QT installation directory, start by renaming larger files/directories (e.g. add a `.old` suffix to the name), and see if the features you use in QT still function.  If it breaks, just rename the files/directories back (remove `.old`).